# Dúvida na realização de branches

Tags: team-foundation-server

Estou com uma dúvida na concorrência de arquivos durante o desenvolvimento de um projeto.

Por exemplo, um time modificou uma DLL no projeto XPTO, depois que desenvolvimento do mesmo foi concluído e antes de ser enviado para homologação foi feito um compare com Produção e verificamos que esta mesma classe foi modificada.

Resolvi o conflito, porém como posso garantir que quando a homologação desta nova feature terminar (talvez demore 1 mês) a mesma DLL irá ser alterada em produção novamente?

Answer (score 0):

Depois da homologação, deve ser feito um merge com `Main`. Isso garantirá que a modificação será repassada para o fluxo principal de desenvolvimento.

Da mesma forma que da primeira vez, provavelmente será necessário resolver mais conflitos.

No link a seguir há um procedimento geral de como proceder (em inglês): http://levelnis.co.uk/blog/tfs-2010-guide-to-branching-and-merging